# Series expansion for $\exp^{-x}$ for $x \to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I know the it will be zero and calculating the leading order term is not straightforward. But is there any way to find out the leading order term for the above expression?

Comment: series for $$e^{-x}$$ in which Point?

Comment: For high $x$, $x \to \infty$

Comment: There is no non-trivial expansion expansion -- when $x\to\infty$, $e^{-x}$ does not behave like/is not well-approximated by any polynomial. If you want an infinite expansion, you have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^n}{n!}$, of course: but truncated this series to the first few terms does not yield any good approximation.